# git merge pull request to private repository

Tags: git, version-control, pull-request

I've cloned some repository from git (dannycoates/v8-profiler) and I have a linkage error while installing it. I saw that someone submitted a pull request which suppose to fix this bug.
Now I want to try and pull this fix into my private local repo, and I was wondering which command to use.
The pull request is titled:

```
piaohai wants to merge 38 commits into dannycoates:master  from piaohai:3.6.2
```

Can I use git pull in this case? how should I use it?

Thanks,
Li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clone the repo where the pull request exists, fetch their branches, make sure you're on the same branch that they are specifying the request for (in this case, master), merge their changes.

```
git remote add piaohai git://github.com/piaohai/v8-profiler.git
git fetch piaohai
git checkout master
git merge piaohai/3.6.2
```